# Is there any Custom Grid Extension for magento 2

Tags: magento2

Recently I have used **"BL_CustomGrid"** For my Magento1 site.

Need to migrate site on Magento2 And looking for Custom Grid Extension.

Anyone have you experience for this please reply me?

Answer (score 0):

Product grid in Magento 2 is more customizable than in Magento 1. 
If setting visibility of columns isn't enought for you, you can check out Amasty's [Extended Product Grid with Editor](https://amasty.com/extended-product-grid-with-editor-for-magento-2.html). It's not the cheapest extension, but it works great.

Comment: Amasty selling order grid and product grid separately. And cost is so high. So we can't consider it.